# a.exe: file not recognized: File truncated

Tags: c++, c, gcc, truncated

It was working perfectly for others c file but in this file it fail to run . Please do explain , as i am new to Programming world.

C:\Desktop\C Basic\recursiveFunction> gcc .\pratice.c

PS C:\Desktop\C Basic\recursiveFunction> gcc .\a.exe

.\a.exe: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, check out the description of the tags that you applied. You can [edit] your question to fix these issues.

Comment: @MemReflect . Thank you so much. file successfully compiled.

Comment: Close voters, please understand that what would be a typo for an experienced programmer is an example of a lack of understanding in a beginner and hence an on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is the compiler.  You compile your program using `gcc .\pratice.c`.  You can remove the `.\` since `gcc` will look in the current directory for source files anyway.

You execute your compiled program using `.\a.exe`.